# Fetch record with max number in one column except if date in that column is > than today

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a problem with fetching few exceptions from DB.

Example, table b:

| sn | v_num | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 01-01-2019 | 31-12-2099 |
| 1 | 002 | 01-01-2021 | 31-01-2022 |
| 1 | 003 | 01-02-2022 | 31-12-2099 |
| 2 | 001 | 01-01-2022 | 31-12-2099 |
| 2 | 002 | 01-07-2022 | 31-07-2022 |
| 2 | 003 | 01-08-2022 | 31-12-2099 |

Expected output:

| sn | v_num | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 003 | 01-02-2022 | 31-12-2099 |
| 2 | 001 | 01-01-2022 | 31-12-2099 |

Currently I'm here:

```
SELECT * FROM table a, table b
WHERE a.sn = b.sn
AND b.v_num = (SELECT max (v_num) FROM b WHERE a.sn = b.sn)
```

but obviously that is not good because of a few cases like this with sn = 2.
Conclusion, I need to get unique sn record where v_num is max (95% of them in DB) except in case if start_date of max v_num record is > today.

Comment: Add `where start_date <= trunc(sysdate())` to the subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter using `start_date <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)` then use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sn ORDER BY v_num DESC) AS rn
  FROM   "TABLE" a
  WHERE  start_date <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

If the `start_date` has a time component then you can use `start_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY` to get all the values for today from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.

If you can have ties for the maximum and want to return all the ties then you can use the `RANK` analytic function instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "TABLE" (sn, v_num, start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT 1, '001', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2099-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '002', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '003', DATE '2022-02-01', DATE '2099-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '001', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2099-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '002', DATE '2022-07-01', DATE '2022-07-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '003', DATE '2022-08-01', DATE '2099-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SN | V_NUM | START_DATE | END_DATE | RN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 003 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 2 | 001 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=673fcc0382373e2cb43a47659bd99d50)*